# Podman on RHEL 8 running out of space during import

Tags: rhel, podman

I am having issues with Podman running out of space when importing.  This is happening on a RHEL 8 VM that has been deployed for our group.  We do have a 80GB /docker partition available, but I am missing some Podman configuration that says to use /docker.  This VM

Can you all help me identify?

Here is part of my /etc/containers/storage.conf:

```
[storage]

# Default Storage Driver, Must be set for proper operation.
driver = "overlay"

# Temporary storage location
runroot = "/docker/temp"

# Primary Read/Write location of container storage
# When changing the graphroot location on an SELINUX system, you must
# ensure  the labeling matches the default locations labels with the
# following commands:
# semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/containers/storage /NEWSTORAGEPATH
# restorecon -R -v /NEWSTORAGEPATH
# graphroot = "/var/lib/containers/storage"
graphroot = "/docker"
```

We are running SELinux, so I did run these commands:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/containers/storage /docker
restorecon -R -v /docker
```

and restart the podman service.  However, if I run

```
podman import docker.tar
```

We receive the error:

```
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 848eb673668a [=>------------------------------------] 1.8GiB / 41.3GiB
Error: writing blob: storing blob to file "/var/tmp/storage2140624383/1": write /var/tmp/storage2140624383/1: no space left on device
```

df -H shows:

```
Filesystem                                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                    3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                       3.9G   84K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                       3.9G  9.3M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                                       3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-root            38G  7.2G   31G  20% /
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-tmp            4.7G   66M  4.6G   2% /tmp
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-home            43G  1.4G   42G   4% /home
/dev/sda2                                   495M  276M  220M  56% /boot
/dev/sdb1                                    79G   42G   33G  56% /docker
/dev/sda1                                   500M  5.9M  494M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-var             33G  1.6G   32G   5% /var
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-var_log        4.7G  109M  4.6G   3% /var/log
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-var_tmp        1.9G   47M  1.9G   3% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-var_log_audit  9.4G  132M  9.2G   2% /var/log/audit
tmpfs                                       785M  8.0K  785M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                                       785M     0  785M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Do you guys know what I'm missing to tell Podman to use /docker instead of /var/tmp/storage2140624383 ?

################################################
**Edited December 29:**

I was able to change the tmpdir to /docker.  However, upon import of this 54GB docker.tar file, it is still telling me I am running out of space.  We were able to import a small .tar (around 800MB) successfully, so we know podman is working.

```
$  podman import docker.tar
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob b45265b317a7 done
Error: writing blob: adding layer with blob "sha256:b45265b317a7897670ff015b177bac7b9d5037b3cfb490d3567da959c7e2cf70": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /a65be6ac39ddadfec332b73d772c49d5f1b4fffbe7a3a419d00fd58fcb4bb752/layer.tar: no space left on device
```

Comment: Maybe related to `TMPDIR`?  _Use the environment variable TMPDIR to change the temporary storage location of downloaded container images. Podman defaults to use /var/tmp_ quote from https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman.1.html#tmpdir-path

Comment: Thanks Erik.  I think you are correct.  I found this link as well:  https://www.reddit.com/r/podman/comments/wgrmgo/change_imagecopytmpdir_to_another_directory/

Answer (score 0):

This might be a pretty easy one:

```
Copying blob 848eb673668a [=>------------------------------------] 1.8GiB / 41.3GiB
```

vs

```
/dev/mapper/rhel_rhel86--svr-var_tmp        1.9G   47M  1.9G   3% /var/tmp
```

As you can see, the image will not fit into the desired temp space directory.

This is somewhat explained in [the docs](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman.1.html#tmpdir-path), which states, you can adjust this by changing the TMPDIR environment variable.

Comment: I did change this with export TMPDIR=/docker  but I am still running into space issues.  I will add to the original post.

Comment: According to your above code samples

`/dev/sdb1                                    79G   42G   33G  56% /docker`

there might not be enough space on `/docker` to unpack 40+ GB.